# Infiniband port status UP but can't open UMAD port ((null):0)

Tags: linux-networking, infiniband

My system has 2 infiniband devices, one of which has both the ports up.

```
$> ibstatus
  Infiniband device 'mlx4_0' port 1 status:
         default gid:     fe80:0000:0000:0000:0002:c903:000f:0a9f
          base lid:        0x22
          sm lid:          0x1
          state:           4: ACTIVE
          phys state:      5: LinkUp
          rate:            20 Gb/sec (4X DDR)
          link_layer:      IB

  Infiniband device 'mlx4_0' port 2 status:
          default gid:     fe80:0000:0000:0000:0002:c903:000f:0aa0
          base lid:        0x23
          sm lid:          0x1
          state:           4: ACTIVE
          phys state:      5: LinkUp
          rate:            20 Gb/sec (4X DDR)
          link_layer:      IB

  Infiniband device 'mlx4_1' port 1 status:
          default gid:     fe80:0000:0000:0000:0002:c903:000f:0a6b
          base lid:        0x0
          sm lid:          0x0
          state:           1: DOWN
          phys state:      2: Polling
          rate:            10 Gb/sec (4X)
          link_layer:      IB

  Infiniband device 'mlx4_1' port 2 status:
          default gid:     fe80:0000:0000:0000:0002:c903:000f:0a6c
          base lid:        0xd
          sm lid:          0x2
          state:           4: ACTIVE
          phys state:      5: LinkUp
          rate:            10 Gb/sec (4X)
          link_layer:      IB
```

Now, when I check the ib port state by lid,

```
 $> ibportstate  -L 10x22 enable
 ibwarn: [14836] mad_rpc_open_port: can't open UMAD port ((null):0)
 ibportstate: iberror: failed: Failed to open '(null)' port '0'
```

I am not sure about the reason for this error message. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just put sudo before ibportstate.

Answer (score 4):

Does the corresponding `umad` device file exist (this is typically `/dev/infiniband/umad0`) ?

Also, on the system I have access to, permissions of `/dev/infiniband/umad0` are set by default such that normal users can't access them:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root root 231, 0 Feb  1 16:00 /dev/infiniband/umad0
```

so you could use `sudo` to run your command (or relax the permissions of `/dev/infiniband/umad0`).

Answer (score 1):

It maybe just a typo here on SO, but you are specifying LID as `10x22`. As LID is supposed to be a hexadecimal number, the 1 is extraneous. It should be just a `0x22`.